# XMPPFramework - How to get currently logged-in user's display name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

In my application utilizing XMPPFramework, I have a login page to authenticate one user.
Once logged in, I wish to show the **`displayName`** of the user in my status page. The displayName is a NSString in **`XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject`**.

The following line returns me the **`XMPPJID`** of my currently logged-in user. I thought this would be useful to check against my roster to get his *displayName*.

```
[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID];
```

However, placing the above in the code below  returns me a *null*.

```
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[[self appDelegate] xmppRosterStorage]
                                           userForJID:[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID]
                                           xmppStream:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]
                                           managedObjectContext:[[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster]];
```

Appreciate any advice on how to go about retrieving the displayName of the current user.

Comment: It will work only if you add yourself to your roster, by default own JID is not in roster.

Comment: @vitalyster : How to add myself to my roster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [vitalyster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097384/vitalyster) mentioned in the comment above, there is no way to retrieve my own display name if I am logged in.

To verify that, I went to my Openfire server settings.

In **Users/Groups** > **User Summary** > **KeithOYS** > **Roster**, there is no same user called **KeithOYS** in the roster list.

Same concept applies for every other users.

---

In a nutshell, every user has all other users in their Roster (as long as they are classified under the same Group), all except himself.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the user name of logged in user with following code.

```
XMPPJID *myjid = [[[self appDelegate]xmppStream]myJID];
NSString *userName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myjid.user];
```

Hope it will help someone.